# Issue getting data from web table using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to connect to a website, with credentials then click a link and get the table it brings to my excel sheet.

I'´m already logged in the site and with the following code I get the table updated but this only works while the excel"from web " connection is alive. I mean, first I have to update the DATA-FROM WEB connection refreshing credentials and then running the macro.

Though the web table is always reached and updated I can't get it pasted to the excel sheet if that connection was updated more that an hour ago.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Descargar_tabla()

  Dim IE As Object

  Set IE = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   IE.Run ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe"" ""https://clientes.invertirenbolsa.com.ar/cart.aspx""")

   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://clientes.invertirenbolsa.com.ar/cart.aspx", Destination:=Range("$L$40"))
       ' .Name = "cart"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "2"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
        Set IE = Nothing

    End With
End Sub
```

What should I add to the code to use the website open session that I already have in the browser which it doesn't expire?

Comment: Are you sure that the website session wont expire? The fact that you are querying from excel leads me to believe that you don't own the site. Therefore, I think the better question would be how do I connect to a site pass the credentials and than download the table.

Comment: Can't reproduce since I have no access to that URL. Why not to try get the table via IE automation or XHR response parsing?